# Is there a power series generating function for Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, power-series, totient-function, formal-power-series

is there a closed form for the expression $\sum_{n \geq 1} \phi(n) x^n$ ?

Everybody knows about the Dirichlet generating function for $\phi$ but I can't find anywhere the power series generating function of $\phi$

Comment: doubt it ${}{}{}$

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204095/residue-for-the-generating-function-of-the-euler-totient-function) is a related question.